# How can i create a new folder with the recently version of my files without take off the old ones for my S3 Bucket in Amazon?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Recently I created a function that send folders with database files to my S3 bucket, in amazon(backup).

I'm using a package called FindIt -> https://github.com/substack/node-findit. I use it to list my files and then send them to my bucket

This is my function:

```
finder.on('file', function (file, stat) {
    var params = {
        Bucket: 'bucket-test-test-my-company',
        Key: file,
        Body: fs.createWriteStream(file)
    };
});

    s3.putObject(params, function(err, res) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            console.log("Success");
        }
        callback(err);
    });
```

Is working perfectly, my folders with the backup files inside are being sent.

This files will be send everyday, and i don't want update, i wan'=t create a new folder with the date or something to know the order..

I really dont know how to do this, help please? Some tutorial maybe?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Key`, in your upload code, is the path where you want the object to live, inside the bucket.

All you have to do is prepend a string representing the "path" of today's backup, such as `backups/daily/2014-20-09/` to the beginning of each filename, before you upload it.

Folders in S3 are not real, so they do not have to be created... but if you add a prefix string to each key, and the prefix contains `/` slashes, then your files will appear, in the S3 console, to be in folders, as you expect.

Note, you should not need a leading `/` in the prefix, but you do need a trailing one.  Just build the string and add it to the beginning of the value you are using for `Key:`.

Alternately, you can enable versioning in the bucket.  When you "overwrite" a file, the one is not deleted -- it merely becomes the "previous version" of the file, and all prior versions remain available, but downloading "the file" without specifying a version will retrieve the most recent version.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Versioning.html

Comment: which do you prefer? i think versioning it's the better option here.

Comment: For backups of databases, where the date/time is very relevant, I use paths with dates, to keep things organized.  For files like image assets that are less likely to change, I use versioning.  Caution: S3 will store a (billable) copy of each version you upload, even if it's identical to another version, so it's up to you to avoid re-uploading a file you've already captured.  The `ETag:` header can be used to determine whether the local file matches the current version.